# Getchar, switching in C

Tags: c, getchar

I am trying to prepend numbers to the "putchar" portion, but because getchar is grabbing a character at a time, the output for "hi" turns to `1 h 2 i`

```
int linecount = 1;
int numberflag = 1;


while (1){
  int input = getchar(); // use int to make sure var input is big enough to hold EOF plus any other char


  switch (input) {
    case EOF:
      exit(-1);

    default:
      if (numberflag){
        printf("\t%d\t", linecount);
        linecount++;
      }
      putchar(input);
      break;
  }
}
```

All help would be appreciated. I am trying to make the output:

```
1 hi 
2 hello
```

and not

```
hi 1
hello 2
```

Comment: You need to set `numberflag` depending on the `char` you got.

Comment: What is numberflag and where did it come from?

Comment: case  '\n': linecount++

Comment: sorry, edited the code to add numberflag to 1. It is enabled by the user passing an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int linecount = 1;
    int numberflag = 1;
    int sol = 1;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (numberflag && sol)
        {
            printf("\t%d\t", linecount++);
            sol = 0;
        }
        if (c == '\n')
            sol = 1;
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output when run on its own source code (`./sol < sol.c`):

```
        1       #include <stdio.h>
        2
        3       int main(void)
        4       {
        5           int linecount = 1;
        6           int numberflag = 1;
        7           int sol = 1;
        8           int c;
        9
        10          while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        11          {
        12              if (numberflag && sol)
        13              {
        14                  printf("\t%d\t", linecount++);
        15                  sol = 0;
        16              }
        17              if (c == '\n')
        18                  sol = 1;
        19              putchar(c);
        20          }
        21          return 0;
        22      }
```